# How can I scroll to specific section?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I'm using Draft JS from Facebook in React.

My `draft` adds decorators on text when the line starts with `# Section name`. In another component on my page, I want to create a link that will make it scroll down to that section when clicked.

```
|-------| ------------|
|Nav    | Draft editor|
|Title 1| # Title 1 |
|.      | Some text |
```

My decorator is pretty basic:

```js
{
    strategy: (contentBlock: any, callback: any) => {
        const REGEX =/^(# .+)$/
        findWithRegex(REGEX, contentBlock, callback)
    },
    component: (props: any) => {
        
        return <h3>{props.children}</h3>
    }

}
```

My Nav link

```js
<a onClick={()=>{
   window.scrollTo() // Scroll to Title 1 in DraftJS
}}>Title 1</a>
```

In the old JS days, I would figure out a way to make an ID and get the element, but it's not the react way.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Here is a [codesandbox to play around](https://codesandbox.io/s/book-editor-vrfqy?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: react also support element by ref https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like it and feels dirty, but in case anyone runs into similar issue, I basically created a function that turns the chapter name into an ID like so:

```js
const chapterToId = (txt: string): string => {
    return txt.trim().split("# ").join("").split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase()
}
```

I then use this function to create a `#` hyperlink like so:

```js
{chapters.map((chapter, i) => {
   const chapterId = chapterToId(chapter);
     return <a
          key={i}
          href={`#${chapterId}`}>
               {chapter}
        </a>      
})}
```

In the draft JS and add the ID to the decorator like so:

```js
const chapters = {
  strategy: (contentBlock: any, callback: any) => {
    const REGEX = /^(# .+)$/gm;
    findWithRegex(REGEX, contentBlock, callback);
  },
  component: (props: any) => {
    const text = props.children[0].props.text;
    const id = chapterToId(text);
    return (
      <h3 id={id} className="text-2xl font-bold mt-4 mb-6">
        {props.children}
      </h3>
    );
  }
}
```

Working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/book-editor-vrfqy?file=/src/components/MyDraft.tsx